# NSTimer setFireDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, timer, cfrunloop

Is considered thread-safe to call setFireDate: from another thread than the one in which the timer is scheduled? I mean, I detach this function in a new thread:

```
-(void)CFRunLoopTest {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();

    CFRunLoopAddTimer(runLoop, (CFRunLoopTimerRef)timer, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

    CFRunLoopRun();
    [pool drain];
}
```

May I call `[timer setFireDate:]` from the main thread? I did not found anything in documentation that forbids it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A note from the [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) reference for `setFireDate:` method says

> You could potentially call this method
>   on a non-repeating timer that had not
>   yet fired, although you should always
>   **do so from the thread to which the
>   timer is attached** to avoid potential
>   race conditions.

Also see if the following
[Discussion](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/232696-nstimer-runloop-questions.html) helps.

Comment: yes but it's talking about "a non-repeating timer that had not yet fired", i wonder if it's valid for all kind of timers...

Answer (score 2):

Why not run the timer on the main thread? I don't understand why you would need to run it in a separate thread. You could always have the timerFireMethod: spawn a new thread if it consumes a lot of time, Just run the appropriate method with `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`.

**EDIT:** So the documentation actually says that it isn't thread safe to call`[timer setFireDate:]` from another thread. However, my advice is still valid.